# Error remaining() < count < needed in GLSurfaceView.Renderer

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to create a triangle in OpenGL ES. But app is crashing for line `gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, pIndex.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, pBuff);` in below code inside `draw` method.

```
public class GLTriangleEx {

    private float vertices[] = {
        0f, 1f, // point 0
        1f, -1f, // point 1
        -1f, -1f // point 2
    };

    private  FloatBuffer vertBuff;

    private short[] pIndex = {0, 1, 2};

    private ShortBuffer pBuff;

    public GLTriangleEx() {
        ByteBuffer bBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertBuff = bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
        vertBuff.put(vertices);
        vertBuff.position(0);

        ByteBuffer pbBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pIndex.length * 2);
        pbBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        pBuff = pbBuff.asShortBuffer();
        pBuff.put(pIndex);
        pbBuff.position(0);
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl){
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);

        // app crashes here.
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, pIndex.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, pBuff);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    }
```

Crash log cat is

```
            java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: remaining() < count < needed
            at com.google.android.gles_jni.GLImpl.glDrawElements(Native Method)
            at com.mobility.opengleslearning.GLTriangleEx.draw(GLTriangleEx.java:45)
            at com.mobility.opengleslearning.GLRenderer.onDrawFrame(GLRenderer.java:38)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1522)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

I have checked below links for help but of no use for my case:

1. [Android OpenGL error: "remaining() < needed" and Android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941756/android-opengl-error-remaining-needed-and-android-4-4)
2. [Beginning to learn OpenGL ES. Drawing quad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265714/beginning-to-learn-opengl-es-drawing-quad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rewind the `ShortBuffer` you use for the indices. In this code:

```
ByteBuffer pbBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pIndex.length * 2);
pbBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
pBuff = pbBuff.asShortBuffer();
pBuff.put(pIndex);
pbBuff.position(0);
```

you're rewinding `pbBuff`, which is the underlying `ByteBuffer`.

`asShortBuffer()` returns a *view buffer* that shares the underlying data with the original buffer. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#views) (emphasis added by me):

> A view buffer is simply another buffer whose content is backed by the byte buffer. Changes to the byte buffer's content will be visible in the view buffer, and vice versa; the **two buffers' position**, limit, and mark values **are independent**.

So `pBuff`, which is your view buffer, has its own position. You need to rewind the view buffer, which is the buffer you use later:

```
pBuff.position(0);
```

Comment: Thanks I will try and get back to you.